# Remove sidebar from all pages in Wordpress (using Wootique)

Tags: wordpress, sidebar

I've been browsing the internet for the past two days looking for a way to remove all sidebars. I don't want any of them, anywhere, ever.
I'm using the Wootique theme if that helps.

Only issue is, I can only access the files via Appearance -> Editor (as I'm only supposed to be updating the site, no access to the server files)

I would also like to know if it's possible to change the "cart" button so it's highlighted in a different color (at all times) and more noticeable.

I'm also kinda an idiot :) so step-by-step for morons would help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to remove the sidebar from the Editor however, the sidebar is possibly in more than one of your theme templates as well as your blog files.  Here's what you do.  First go to a page that currently has a sidebar that you don't want as if you were going to edit it.  Look at the Page Attributes on the right and note what you have selected in the template drop down menu. If you have "Default Template" selected then you will need to edit the "Page Template" file from your Editor, it will say "page.php" underneath "Page Template" in any theme including yours.  However, if you had a different template selected in the page that you went to edit i.e. "Full Width" then take note of that and look for the "Full Width" page on the editor.  Next select the page you want to edit in the editor and look for the sidebar code so you can delete it.  It will look something like the code below.

```
<?php get_sidebar();} ?>
```

Once you have found the sidebar code simply delete it and save your changes.  The sidebar should now be gone from the template you edited.

To help you with the cart button you might want to post a link.  The color can be changed in the CSS file but I can't walk you through it without looking at the css.

Hope it helps

Comment: Removing the <?php get_sidebar();} ?> from the default template didn't remove the side bar. Just in case, I also tried removing everything from sidebar.php and sidebar-init.php. Still nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove the sidebar from the Editor however, the sidebar is possibly in more than one of your theme templates as well as your blog files. Here's what you do. First go to a page that currently has a sidebar that you don't want as if you were going to edit it. Look at the Page Attributes on the right and note what you have selected in the template drop down menu. If you have "Default Template" selected then you will need to edit the "Page